# Tensorflow: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops' has no attribute 'case'

Tags: python, tensorflow

hey im currently working on a tensorflow project im usint python 3.11.0 and tensorflow 2.14.0

m getting this error, how can i resolve this?

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops' has no attribute 'case'

check the file the error came from, also checked the libraries

Answer (score 5):

try to use `tensorflow 2.13.0` instead of the newest one. place this  before the verification script:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.13.0
```

it worked in my case and made it possible to train the dataset

Comment: Indeed, downgrading tensorflow's version to 2.13.0 makes training work. Worked for me as well on Colab.

Answer (score 5):

to fix this problem if you're using Ubuntu:

open this file :

> home > user > .local > lib > python3.11 > site-packages > tf_slim > data > tfexample_decoder.py

first, add `import tensorflow as tf` at the top, then change these parts of the code

at line 453 instead of

`image = control_flow_ops.case(pred_fn_pairs, default=check_jpeg, exclusive=True)`

put this

`image = tf.case(pred_fn_pairs, default=check_jpeg, exclusive=True)`

and other places if used `control_flow_ops` put `tf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@Hesam760](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22775389/hesam760) above,
Modifying other places if used `control_flow_ops` put `tf`.

**Don't modify line 38 to**: `from tensorflow.python.ops import tf`

**Make it like this**: `from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops`

I tried Changing line 38 to `from tensorflow.python.ops import tf` but it shows an error, after leaving it at `from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops` it worked well.

Thank you