# image = control_flow_ops.case( AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops' has no attribute 'case'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

image = control_flow_ops.case(    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops' has no attribute 'case' i get this error during train my custom dataset with pretrained SSD model ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8 in colab python version is 3.10.12 and tensor flow 2.15.0 also try 2.14 and 2.13. tell me any solution about it. i try many ways but i cant solve this

expecting dataset is trained

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.ops.control\_flow\_ops' has no attribute 'case'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247945/tensorflow-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-ops-control-flow-ops-has)